# I have generated a keystore. How to add it to visual studio project properly?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, keystore

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying a basic application Android template. The program can't be installed on my emulator because it is not signed by a keystore and the error is (No certificates). I am wondering how to add the keystore to the project the right way to make the program works. Any help is appreciated.

> 2>Error installing package '{0}', the package is not signed with a
> .keystore. Please sign the package and deploy the package again.
>
> 2>The
> package manager failed to install the apk:
> '/data/local/tmp/Hello_World.apk' with the error code:
> 'NoCertificates'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with Visual Studio but in AS You can add in gradle keystore file. Maybe it will help You.

```
 android {
        // 1. USER EXAMPLE How to add debug.keystore in gradle
        // Default debug.keystore settings
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/USER/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }


 buildTypes {
        }
        debug {
            // 2. USER EXAMPLE How to add debug.keystore in gradle
              signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

Comment: build.gradle (Module: your_app_name_here)

Comment: Add debug buildType like release. Put signingConfig in release/debug buildTypes.
And config put inside "android" tag

Comment: I solved the problem on my own, thank you. If you can answer my next problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242213/the-emulator-is-supposed-to-recognize-the-apk-as-signed-but-it-does-not